# Not getting the "name" of custom attribute by ElementRef

Tags: angular, validation, components, directive

I am using the "name" of components for conditions(if, else).
I am trying to get it by the ElementRef's nativeElement property.
It is working fine with elements like(input, textarea), but getting undefined for my custom component.

```
import { BasicPermissionService } from './../components/basicpermission.service';
import { Directive, forwardRef, Input, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALIDATORS, AbstractControl, ValidatorFn, Validator, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
   selector: '[ifRequired][ngModel]',
   providers: [
      { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: ifRequiredValidator, multi: true }
   ]
})
export class ifRequiredValidator implements Validator {
validator: ValidatorFn;

constructor(private elem: ElementRef, private basicPermissionService: BasicPermissionService) {
    this.validator = this.ifRequiredValidateFactory(elem.nativeElement.name);
}

validate(c: FormControl) {
    return this.validator(c);
}

ifRequiredValidateFactory(control: string): ValidatorFn {
    return (c: AbstractControl) => {
        let isRequired = this.basicPermissionService.basicSectionIsRequired(control);
        let isValid = false;
        //if field is not required then do nothing
        if (!isRequired) {
            return null;
        }
        switch (true) {
            case typeof c.value == "number":
                isValid = c.value != null && c.value != 0;
                break;               
                ...
        }

        if (isValid) {
            return null;
        } else {
            let validatioMessage = (control: string) => {
                switch (control) {
                    case "name":
                        return "Mandatory field";
                    ...
                }
            }
            return {
                ifRequired: {
                    valid: false,
                    message: validatioMessage(control)
                }
            };
        }
    }
   }
 }
```

It is working for

```
 <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="basicInfo.Name" maxlength="200" placeholder="Name" name="name"
                     maxlength="2000" #name="ngModel"
                    ifRequired/>
```

But not for

```
<radio-select [IsMultiple]="true" [FieldType]="eventTypeField"
                            [SelectedIds]="basicInfo.EventTypeIds"
                            [(ngModel)]="basicInfo.EventTypeIds" [rname]="'EventType'" name="EventType"
                             #EventType="ngModel" ifRequired>
                        </radio-select>
```

Comment: please give some clarity and highlight the required parts and remove unnecessary parts

Comment: Thanks everyone, I got the element/component name by attribute using elem.nativeElement.attributes["name"].value. It is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correct, you are trying to get access to the Component which is referred in the HTML using selector "radio-select". You can use the below code:

HTML:

```
<radio-select [IsMultiple]="true" [FieldType]="eventTypeField"
                        [SelectedIds]="basicInfo.EventTypeIds"
                        [(ngModel)]="basicInfo.EventTypeIds" [rname]="'EventType'"name="EventType"
                         #EventType="ngModel" ifRequired
                          #radioSelectComponent>
                    </radio-select>
```

Component:

@ViewChild('radioSelectComponent') radioSelectComponent:

You can now reference the component using the variable 'radioSelectComponent' and hence access all its members.

Answer (score 0):

Add an **input property** for `name` in directive class.

```
@Input() name: string;
```

Then try accessing name property instead of accessing attribute through `ElementRef` object.

Hope it helps!